# Unable to boot from a bootable CD in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, bootable-media

I have a Dell media disk which i have placed in my laptop for a clean install.

Under the Bios settings I have set the boot priority 1st priority to CD/DVD in the BIOS settings and pressed F10 to save.

Now as the first priority was to boot from CD/DVD then why is the laptop booting from the hard drive

The disk is completely new with no scratches/physical damage.

Even after setting the priority to CD the OS gets loaded by default from the hard drive

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Here is [Dell](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN130608/EN)'s recommended guidelines for your problem. Note the box in yellow; seems like Dell staff predicted your issue.

> Reinstall Windows 7 using the Dell Operating System Installation Disc.
>
> To run the installation disc, insert the Windows installation disc
>   into the DVD drive. Restart your computer. When the Press any key to
>   boot from the CD or DVD message appears, press any key to continue.
>
> **If the disc does not begin to run, press your computer's Power button and watch for the Dell logo to appear. When the logo appears,
>   press the F12 key to load the Boot menu.  If this menu does not
>   appear, try restarting your computer again and pressing F12several
>   times when the Dell logo appears. Once the Boot menu opens, select
>   CD/DVD drive (listed also as CD-Rom or CD/DVD/CD-RW) and press
>   Enter.**
>
> When Windows 7 Setup appears, confirm that the Language, Time,
>   Currency and Keyboard Method fields display the correct settings.
>
> On the Windows 7 Installation dialog box, click Install Now.
>
> Review the license agreement, and click I accept the license terms.
>
> On the Which type of installation do you want? window, click Custom
>   (advanced).
>
> On the Where do you want to install Windows window, select the largest
>   internal disc as the Primary Partition, then click Next. If the
>   Primary Partition shows 0GB free, select Unallocated Space and click
>   Next.
>
> Your computer will restart.
>
> Personalize and customize your Windows 7 operating system by following
>   the instructions on the following screens.
>
> When your Desktop screen appears, you are ready for the next step.

Comment: I feel you have misinterpret the question I don't want on how to install Windows I have already done the settings but still it does not load the bootable disk

Comment: @user285oo6 Load BIOS default and boot CD.

Comment: And how do you boot it @STTR

Comment: Load BIOS default?

Comment: @user285oo6 "I need to do a clean install of my Operating system." is what you posted, you need to re-write your question if this is not what you are having problems with

Comment: @Moab  As  the title is "Unable to boot from a bootable CD in Windows 7" then how can you go for that.Any ways I have edited hope it resolves your doubts

Answer (score 0):

I suspect we have an [X/Y Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) here.

**X Y Problem:** Obviously, there's an issue with the drive and/or disc.

**Solution:**Download win 7 from digital river and load it to a USB using the windows usb iso tool from Microsoft and boot to win7 iso via Bootable USB. Done and Done.

**SEE:** [Where can I download Windows 7 (legally from Microsoft)?](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft)

Since there's an issue with the drive and/or disc, download bootable iso to USB.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool

Resolves the root issue: Need new OS install on local disk.